# New MikTeX installation inherits an error

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

My previous installation became unusable because of errors like
"Argument of@expl@@@filehook@file@pop@assign@@nnnn has an extra ..."

So I've done a complete uninstall and reinstall of basic-miktex-23.10-x64 on Windows 11.  And I'm getting this error "! Argument of \begin  has an extra }."

I've added a MinionPro tag because I suspect this was the problem with the original installation.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}                 
\begin{document}
                
\begin{wraptable}
\begin{tabular}
C1      &C2\\
1       &2  \\
9       &16 \\
11      &9  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 

Oh, woe is me!
\end{document}
```

The full message is

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.1 (MiKTeX 23.12)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
 (C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def) (./mwe.aux)
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Argument of \begin  has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.9 \begin
        {tabular}

The log file is
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.1 (MiKTeX 23.12) (format=lualatex 2024.1.26)  26 JAN 2024 22:00
 restricted system commands enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/f
ontloader-2023-08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (C:/Users/myuser/AppData
/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen140
\WF@size=\dimen141
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count193
\WF@box=\box51
\WF@everypar=\toks17
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
(C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
) (./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = mwe.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay
```

Comment: Both the syntax of the `tabular` and `warptable` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I was getting there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the syntax of the `tabular` and `warptable` is wrong. At the very minimum you have to specify the mandatory arguments of both environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}                 
\begin{document}
                
\begin{wraptable}{r}{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
C1      &C2\\
1       &2  \\
9       &16 \\
11      &9  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 

Oh, woe is me!
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll look at the issue of producing a worthwile MWE tomorrow.  In thre meanwhile the live system (nwely-born) system produces "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/MinionPro(0)/m/scsl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/MinionPro(0)/m/scit' instead on input line 425.

[12])
! Argument of \@expl@@@filehook@file@pop@assign@@nnnn has an extra }."

Comment: Thanks Sam.  That;s the issue here all right.  And the problem seems to have "gone away" in the live system.